# Inverse predict the features from known target with fitted sklearn regressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, predictive-modeling

I understand that the default way a scikit-learn regressor works is that we fit it to a dataset of features and targets (`X_train`, `y_train`) and then we can use the fitted regressor to predict an unknown target, `y1`, from known features, `X1`.

On the contrary, I know the target, `y1`, and would like to evaluate what features `X1` would yield the known target with the fitted regressor.

I do not think that there is an in-built method (such as `inverse_predict`) that can achieve this, or is there such a method???

How do you suggest I efficiently estimate `X1`?

Here is a horribly inefficient way I am doing this presently:

```py
from sklearn.svm import SVR
reg = SVR(kernel='linear')
reg.fit(X_train, y_train) 

# While loop to estimate X1
continue_while_loop = True
while continue_while_loop:
    X1 = X_train[np.random.choice(range(X_train.shape[0]),:]  # randomly select a feature vector from X_train
    X1 = X1 + np.random.normal(np.mean(X_train), 10*np.std(X_train), (X_train.shape))  # Add random noise to X1
    y1pred = reg.predict(X1.reshape(1,-1))
    error = np.linalg.norm(y1 - y1pred) # Find the error between predicted and true y1
    if error < 1e-2:
        continue_while_loop = False

print(y1, y1pred)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. I think if you want to evaluate what features X1 would yield y1, you can just look at the current dataset and use the rows that have a value of y1, those are the set of features that would yield y1. However, if you want to estimate or generalize, you can calculate a mean() median(), or some other statistic of each column for each value of y1. No matter what you do, predicting several values from one value is much more difficult than predicting one value from several values.

Comment: My dataset does not contain y1. I would like to evaluate what features would lead to y1. Maybe I can look at the closest value in my dataset to y1 and interpolate the features? Was hoping there would be a more accurate/efficient way.

Comment: Do you have more than one feature?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin, (`X_train`, `y_train`) is a set of 1000 features and targets, but `y1` is a single value. And `y1` is not in the dataset.

Comment: Do you mean that you have 1000 samples in your dataset, or that you have 1000 features?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I mean 1000 samples. Each feature is a 24-D vector.